# Docker mysql container doesn't persist data despite using volumes. Why?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, adminer

I am running two docker containers.

- mysql
- adminer

I want to persist my database, therefore I use **volumes** in my docker-compose file. Still I lose data whenever I restart the containers (docker-compose down and up).

What I am missing? (I am on ubuntu 20.04)

```
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'example' # TODO: Change this      
    volumes:
      - "./config/my.conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf"
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

Comment: check you ./data folder does it have any files create if not it will not persisted.

Comment: it's empty. even after I created a new database.

Comment: @Sanyifejű could you update the question with the contents of the `my.conf`file? You've probably changed the default datadir.

Comment: @ timsmelik   'my.conf'  is not a file but a directory and it is empty. (I copy pasted the yaml-file volumnes-line from a tutorial, which did not tell much about the content of the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker-compose stop` instead of `docker-compose down`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> docker-compose down:
> Stops containers and **removes** containers, networks, **volumes**, and images created by up.

Comment: It should not remove volume mounts.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Data in a bind mount shouldn't get deleted. It looks to me that MySQL isn't writing it's data to `/var/lib/mysql` as @timsmelik has inferred. Did you change the default data dir in your conf file? The behaviour with stop/down seems to suggest your data is being written to an anonymous volume that is managed by the docker compose lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue

just remove " (quotation marks) from

```
- "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

and write it without them.

```
- ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

you can easily run `docker-compose down` and your data will be persistent

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose down -v removes the volume associated .create a named volume will solve the problem

```
volumes:
  - my-data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).